# C# Background Workers - How many should I use simultaneously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker

I'm writing an MVVM (Caliburn.Micro) application in C# which uses PowerShell to run WMI queries on remote computers. The computers are loaded from a selected Active Directory OU, so there could be any number of them. The results from the WMI queries will be displayed on the UI and I want to run multiple queries simultaneously and display each one as soon as its query has completed. I'm using multiple background workers to achieve this and at the moment it's working. However my current code will create one background worker for each computer in the OU without any form of queue or limit.

```
private void QueryComputers()
{
    foreach (RemoteComputer computer in Computers)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        bw.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(computer.DNSHostName);
    }

}
```

I imagine if there was enough computers in the selected OU that this could have a large performance impact. How many simultaneous background workers should I limit this to? Would you use a static number or base it on the number of CPU cores?

Also, how would you implement the queue for this? I thought about doing something like this:

```
private int bwCount = 0;
private int bwLimit = 5; // 10, 20, 200??

private void QueryComputers()
{
    int stopAt = lastIndex + (bwLimit - bwCount);
    if (stopAt > Computers.Count - 1) stopAt = Computers.Count - 1;
    if (stopAt > lastIndex)
    {
        for (int i = lastIndex; i <= lastIndex + (bwLimit - bwCount); i++) {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
            bw.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync(Computers[i].DNSHostName);

            lastIndex = i;
            bwCount++;
        }
    }
}

private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle Result etc...

    bwCount--;
    QueryComputers();
}
```

**EDIT:**

**Attempt at using Task Parallel Library**

I've taken one method from my application which retrieves the logged on user from the remote machine and attempted to use TPL instead of a background worker. The problem is it's not running asynchronously and the UI is hanging while it runs.

```
private void GetLoggedOnUsersTPL()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Computers, (computer) =>
    {
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {

            computer.Status = RemoteComputer.ComputerStatus.UpdatingStatus;

            // Ping the remote computer to check if it's available to connect to
            ps.AddScript($"Test-Connection -ComputerName {computer.DNSHostName} -Count 1 -Quiet");
            Collection<PSObject> psOutput = ps.Invoke();
            if ((bool)psOutput[0].BaseObject) // If the computer responded to the Ping
            {
                ps.Commands.Clear(); // Remove the Test-Connection (Ping) command

                // Use a WMI query to find out who is logged on to the remote computer
                ps.AddScript($"Get-CimInstance -ComputerName {computer.DNSHostName} -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property UserName");
                psOutput = ps.Invoke();

                if (psOutput.Count < 1) // If there are no results we will try using a DCOM connection instead of WSMAN
                {
                    ps.Commands.Clear();
                    ps.AddScript("$opt = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol DCOM");
                    ps.AddScript($"$cims = New-CimSession -ComputerName {computer.DNSHostName} -SessionOption $opt");
                    ps.AddScript($"Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property UserName -CimSession $cims");
                    psOutput = ps.Invoke();
                }

                if (psOutput.Count > 0) // Check if we had any results
                {
                    string userName = psOutput[0].Members["UserName"].Value.ToString();
                    if (userName == null || userName == "")
                    {
                        computer.LoggedOnUser = "Nobody is logged on...";
                        computer.Status = RemoteComputer.ComputerStatus.Online;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        computer.LoggedOnUser = userName;
                        computer.Status = RemoteComputer.ComputerStatus.Online;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    computer.Status = RemoteComputer.ComputerStatus.Blocked;
                }

            }
            else
            { 
                computer.Status = RemoteComputer.ComputerStatus.Offline;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried making the method `async` I.e. `private async void GetLoggedOnUsersTPL()` but that told me I need to use `await`, and I'm not sure where to use that in this example.

**EDIT 2:**

**Second attempt at using Task Parallel Library**

I'm now trying to use Task.Run instead of Parallel.ForEach which is working mostly. The tasks are executing and the UI is NOT hanging, but if I select a new OU from the TreeView before all of the tasks have finished executing the debugger breaks on the `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` lines, so they are not being caught. Is anybody able to point out what I've done wrong here please?

```
public override bool IsSelected // << AD OU IsSelected in TreeView
{
    get { return isSelected; }
    set
    {
        if (isSelected != value)
        {
            isSelected = value;

            if (getLoggedOnUsersTokenSource != null) // If any 'GetLoggedOnUsers' tasks are still running, cancel them
            {
                getLoggedOnUsersTokenSource.Cancel(); 
            }

            LoadComputers(); // Load computers from the selected OU
            GetLoggedOnUsersTPL();
        }
    }
}

private CancellationTokenSource getLoggedOnUsersTokenSource;
private async void GetLoggedOnUsersTPL()
{
    getLoggedOnUsersTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = getLoggedOnUsersTokenSource.Token;

    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    foreach (RemoteComputer computer in Computers)
    {
        taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => GetLoggedOnUsersTask(computer, token), token));

    }

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    } catch (OperationCanceledException) // <<<< Not catching all cancelled exceptions
    {
        getLoggedOnUsersTokenSource.Dispose();
    }

}

private void GetLoggedOnUsersTask(RemoteComputer computer, CancellationToken token)
{
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        // Ping remote computer to check if it's online

        if ((bool)psOutput[0].BaseObject) // If the computer responded to the Ping
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            // Run WMI query to get logged on user using WSMAN

            if (psOutput.Count < 1) // If there were no results, try DCOM
            {

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                // Run WMI query to get logged on user using DCOM

                // Process results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious as to why you are using `BackgroundWorker` instead of the Parallel Task Library?

Comment: The simple answer to that is I've never heard of it lol. I program as a hobby and haven't ever had any training, just pick things up as I come across a new problem. I believe multi-threading can get quite complicated and figured background worker might be the easiest method, especially as I've used them before.

Comment: How would the Parallel Task Library benefit in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, it's better at having more than one going at a time.

Comment: The Task Parallel Library (stated incorrectly above) is extremely easy to use and has many advanced features. In some cases even leveraging more power out of the host system then BW. But, that said, I have used BW extensively in the long past--it serves its purpose. So if you feel comfortable, then go with that. [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) gives some really good advice, but bare in mind this blog is also over 7 years old.

Comment: TPL has some methods that allow you to really fine tune your application. I also really like the ability to add a `CancellationToken` if needed. With TPL one generally takes an approach that best suits the needs for either I/O process or a CPU bound process. It sound like you are offloading work to other machines...so this would be an example of I/O process.

Comment: I've had a go at using `Parallel.ForEach()` as suggested, but I'm doing something wrong. I've updated my question to show what I've done. I will need to continue with this tomorrow, but any help on this in the meantime would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using powershell?

Comment: It does not matter.  BGW uses the threadpool to execute DoWork, you can't overload it.  No reason to throw away working code.

Comment: @CSharpie I remember back when I was using Exchange 2010 that the GUI used to run PowerShell commands in the background which I found interesting. We've also recently purchased some software which synchronises our MIS and AD data with GSuite and Office 365, which also uses PowerShell in the background. Our main file server has a large number of disk quotas which take a long time to populate. So I wanted to write an app which could take an AD username and lookup/edit the single users quota quickly, preferably without needing to use Remote Desktop. (continues in next comment...)

Comment: I did some searching and found that the easiest way to achieve this is using PowerShell which my colleges are not familiar with. So I used a similar method with C# and PowerShell to obtain and edit the quotas (and the user's home directory from AD). I just decided to write this application the same way because PowerShell already has a set of functions to do everything I need. I could remove PowerShell and still achieve everything with C# but this application is only going to run a few commands on remote machines and display the results, so I'm not sure if it's worth the extra work.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, that's good to know. However I think I will still pursue the TPL method in the name of education :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks. I'm using Task.Run now and it seems to be working a lot better (I.e. the UI isn't hanging anymore), but the cancellation isn't working correctly. I've updated the question again with details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using multiple background workers to achieve this and at the moment it's working.

`BackgroundWorker` is a rather outdated type that doesn't handle dynamic requirements well. `Parallel` is a better approach if your workload is synchronous (which it appears to be).

> The problem is it's not running asynchronously and the UI is hanging while it runs.

The `Parallel.ForEach` is a great solution. To unblock the UI, just push it onto a thread pool thread. So this parallel method:

```
private void GetLoggedOnUsersTPL()
{
  Parallel.ForEach(Computers, (computer) =>
  {
    ...
  });
}
```

should be called as such:

```
await Task.Run(() => GetLoggedOnUsersTPL());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an application to move financial records from one General Ledger database to the next in a WPF app. Each operation was independent and ran on a background thread and would at times spring to life or sit dormant and report back to the view of the wpf app which dutifully recorded their live statuses.

During testing my thought was to ultimately throttle the total operations to ensure smooth operations.

That throttling was *never* implemented and I released the app to production where differing people ran the app targeting their specific schemas.

So my advice is to do similar, you can run upwards of 200 threads doing internal asynchronous operations without breaking a sweat...so it depends on the loads of the operations and what they are doing which have more of a bearing on that decision than a specific number.

Comment: So there wouldn't be a problem with creating so many instances of PowerShell which are all connecting to remote computers via a CIM session either?

Comment: Depends on the resources of the computer at the time and how power shell handles being in a threaded operation.